# Does Googles App Engine "Cloud Firestore Stored Data" quota include overhead data(metadata, indexes, etc.)?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out what the overhead of my data will be given the automatic indexing that happens with Firestore.

First I understand that you are charged for the amount of data that you store in Cloud Firestore, including storage overhead.

I've also read through the Firebase documentation on calculating document size for Firestore in native mode. I used that to calculate a rough estimate of a document, the full collection, and the size of the automatic indexes.

I am looking for a way to check that my calculations are correct. The closest thing I've found is Googles App Engine "Cloud Firestore Stored Data" quota. However, based on my calculations and testing, it seems to me that this only includes user added data and not the automatically created indexes or other metadata. Is that correct? and if so, is there any other way to figure out how much data I have in my Firestore DB besides calculating it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

**Update** : Previous answer was for Firestore in Datastore mode but OP's question is about Firestore in Native Mode. The answer has been updated to reflect Firestore in Native Mode

I can't find any direct answer but I would infer it does by looking at the following documentations

1. [Quotas documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/quotas) breaks down the different parts of the quota and it includes a section on indexes
2. [Storage Size documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/storage-size) also has an entry for calculating the size of the index which leads me to conclude it affects your storage size which in turn is part of your quota

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What you linked me is firestore in datastore mode, not native mode. As I mentioned above, I understand that I'm charged for the total amount of storage (created data + overhead), for both datastore and native modes. However - that isnt the question I asked. I'm asking if Googles App Engine "Cloud Firestore Stored Data" quota includes the overhead. I've read through their documentation explaining the details and there are no explanations (that I've found) of firestore storage resources.

Comment: I agree with the updated post, I cant find any direct answers either. The documentation talks about Blobstore stored data and Datastore stored data but doesn't mention Firestore. I decided to test it and used their documents to calculated the size of a collection and added said collection to Firestore. It looks like the quota for Firestore stored data doesn't include any overhead... This is where my original question comes from. I'm left to assume...  either I'm correct in my assumptions or my math is wrong.